# Using Apache camel in bundles on Apache karaf

Tags: maven, stream, apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf

I'm trying to write the content of some files into the log file of Apache karaf (just for some testing). To do that I use the following Route with Camel:

```
from("file:C:/input?noop=true").process(new LogProcessor()).to(
            "stream:out");
```

The LogProcessor does nothing right now and my pom.xml looks like this (building it with maven):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<!--

    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>osgi</groupId>
<artifactId>osgi</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<name>osgi Bundle</name>
<description>osgi OSGi bundle project.</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-stream</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>osgi</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</Bundle-Version>
                    <Bundle-Activator>osgi.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                    <Export-Package>
                        osgi*;version=1.0-SNAPSHOT
                    </Export-Package>
                    <Import-Package>
                        *
                    </Import-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I also executed

```
features:install camel-stream
```

on karaf and of course camel itself is also installed on karaf.

But still I get the

```
[...]No component found with scheme: stream[...]
```

Error on karaf.

Already looked through a lot of Forums and stuff but couldn't find any solution...any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is bit of a hunch but I'm guessing you've created DefaultCamelContext inside bundle Activator. Then Stream Component is not loaded in to that context unless you do it yourself like this:

```
StreamComponent stream = new StreamComponent();
camelContext.addComponent("stream", stream);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the problem and now it finally works :) - is this the way to solve this problem or is there any other "best practice" solution? For example I got a simliar problem when trying to use CSV but there is no CsvComponent or something like this to add

Comment: If you create DefaultCamelContext yourself then you have to add components by hand. If you are willing to use Spring then it will create CamelContext automatically for you with all available Components. See http://camel.apache.org/spring.html If you have nothing against using Spring then that's my recommendation. Note that then you won't use Bundle Activator anymore since Spring will activate your CamelContext and add routes to it.

Comment: spring works fine when starting in a console with 'mvn:camel run' but doesn't work when deploying it on Apache karaf

Comment: Spring based bundles should work when deployed to Apache Karaf, if it doesn't then you have some configuration error or something. If you can't figure it out, I recommend opening a new question about Spring based bundle in Karaf with the error that you are facing.

Comment: ok i did that. You still got any idea how to get things like csv or cxf to work without spring? Because there is no Component to add but still the same error in karaf

Comment: You can check from the Camel source code what those components register to the context with the schemes that you get errors. For instance camel-csv component will register class  org.apache.camel.dataformat.csv.CsvDataFormat with name "csv" (the name comes from the filename). See here https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-csv/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/dataformat/csv

Comment: But I can't add a DataFormat as a Component

Comment: I suppose you should add it to the the [Registry](http://camel.apache.org/registry.html) then. I just don't see any particular reason why you would want to go over the trouble when you can use .marshall(new CsvDataFormat()) if that's what you are doing.

Comment: If you are going to deploy to Karaf by far the easiest way is to work with blueprint. It does have some headaches with Camel but overall it makes it much easier for deploying to karaf. In most circumstances it works same as the java dsl.